# PHP limit string to x then cut li and store it in a value for later use

Tags: php, string, concatenation, limit

I have this html as a description

```
<p>Intro Description here</p>
<ul>
<li>Magnetic numbers are perfect for steel safety scoreboards.</li>
<li>Numbers are white and are 20-mil thick and 2" high. </li>
<li>Sold in full packages of 10 numbers (0-9).</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to have like say 90 character limits, so in this particular example, It ends in the second `<li>`. How can I cut and store (it in a variable for later use, same page) the second and third `<li>` completely ignoring the 90 character limit. I mean, if the 90th character falls under the second `<li>`, that `<li>` and its content will be cut off and stored in a variable.

Comment: not easy. simplest is to run through the dom tree section by section, and count characters until you hit the limit. then you know which element you're in to do the slicing, and can nuke any following elements.

Comment: I edited the store value you might be confused with that. Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to get ul elements like this:

```
$u = $dom->getElementsByTagName("ul");
```

Get inner html

```
$str = $u->saveHTML() ;
```

Complete code (assuming that you only want parts inside `<ul> </ul>` tags)

```
$html = "Your html string"
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$u = $dom->getElementsByTagName("ul"); 
$str = $u->saveHTML() ;
$string = substr($str,0,90)  //getting only 90 chars
```

Comment: How about the part where ignoring the `<li>`?

Comment: I am assuming you do not want to count html tags like <li>? $dom->plainText will give you just that

Comment: I tested your code and even if i echo $string, I still get the plain text

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking, you mentioned that you want no html tags(plain text) right ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question for your reference. Thanks!